# Can I use the Maven release plugin directly with git-svn?

Tags: maven, git-svn

At work, most people still host their code in Subversion.  If I want to work with one of these projects, I usually check it out with git-svn.  The only catch is that if I want to cut a release with Maven, I have to pull a separate SVN release and build from that directly, because (as far as I can tell) [Maven doesn't understand git-svn](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SCM-623?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3achangehistory-tabpanel).

It looks like this has been [on the radar for many years](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/200902.mbox/%3Ca6b2caf40902151235l121bb607oa33d8f5913515e52@mail.gmail.com%3E), without forward movement.  Is there any kind of alternative, that doesn't involve a complete separate (native SVN) copy of the entire repository just for cutting releases?  It seems like it would be common enough that somebody would have made a workaround by now.

Comment: Why would you like to use git-svn instead svn or git directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven can use either SVN or GIT directly but not git-svn.

Comment: OK, sure, but is there any less-awful workaround than what I'm doing now?

Comment: Why not using svn or git directly?

Comment: As I said, it's not my project, so I can't determine how the project is stored -- the original authors chose SVN and I'm stuck with it.  However, I prefer Git's repository model so I can make frequent local checkins and do local branching for feature development.  Git-svn is awesome for this, except for the part where it doesn't support Maven releases.

Comment: So the original project can do the releases. So where is the problem? Why do you need to do releases with Maven?

Comment: I am contributing to an "open-source" (within my organization) project.  If somebody makes a feature request, I can check it out, make the changes, release a new version, and close the ticket.  We don't have a CI server or dedicated "release manager" in our workflow.

Comment: So you can do this with SVN. So where is the problem? Why do you really need git-svn for that? Ok you can work locally with git ok but if you're ready you push back the changes into the SVN and afterwards you can release a new version which is based on SVN. So i don't see a problem there. May be you can elaborate that a little bit more what exactly your problem is.

Comment: I would prefer not to maintain two separate checkouts of the code.  Right now, I need one working copy for active development (with git-svn), and a totally separate copy for releases (with plain SVN).  This seems wasteful and silly, and would really be a problem if my projects were very large.

Comment: Why not working with SVN only in this case? How large is your project? (in git-svn and the working copy in SVN?)

Comment: The particular project I asked about is not large, only a web application with a dozen or so source files and the whole repository is only a few MB on disk.  However, I also follow this flow for much larger projects sometimes.  As I said, I'd really prefer to use the git workflow (local branching, frequent local checkins) which is why I use git-svn instead of native SVN.

Comment: Than it might be better to migrate the project to git on GitHub etc.

Comment: As I said earlier, it's not my call how we host it, that decision was already made elsewhere and I am only a lowly user of the pre-selected source control service (SVN).  I just want to avoid the pitfalls of SVN (infrequent, remote-only commits and terrible merging) using the only really good tool I have at my disposal (git-svn).  I had hoped to avoid crappy workarounds and still get the benefits of Git, but it looks like the crappy workaround is all I can do.  Sorry to drag this out.

Comment: Creating a branch and merging back those changes to trunk/other brach etc. works very well in SVN so that's not the reason. remote-only commits might be reason. Why not having a CI tools which will handle the releases? BTW: Can you say which open source project we are talking about?